# Does 丢 mean "discard" as well as "throw" and "lose"?

Tags: translation, meaning

On a Chinese teaching site [they are translating 丢 as "throw away"](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/28315194) but Pleco, English Wiktionary, and Google Translate do not include "throw away" as a translation of 丢 or include 丢 as a translation for "throw away" or "discard".

Are these resources missing this common sense of 丢? Or Has the common non-native English confusion of "throw" and "throw away" influenced the site?

Comment: @user6065 Users? What users? Users **are** flagging your comments as *no longer needed*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

丟主要有兩個意思：

(1)扔、拋棄(throw)。如：「丟球」、「丟垃圾」。

(2)遺失、失去(lose)。如：「丟臉」、「丟飯碗」。

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the original meaning of「丟」was *to throw away*:

> 元・康進之《李逵負荆》：＂把煩惱都也波丟，都丟在腦背後。＂
>
> *Throw away [your] worries/troubles; throw them all to the back of [your] mind*.

「丟」is comprised of semantic「一」(representing *something [to be thrown away]*) and semantic「去」(*to leave, go > abandon*).

> 《揚子・方言》：＂丟，一去不還也。＂
>
> 「丟」, *to abandon* (去) *something* (一) *[such that it does] not* (不) *return* (還).

As mentioned elsewhere, *to throw away* is now replaced by「扔」, unless you're speaking in a regional colloquialism or to elderly people.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is acceptable (maybe it is correct in some dialects) to use 丢 as the meaning of **throw**, I suggest that using 扔 (or other words) instead. Since idiomatically we say 把球传过来 or 把球抛过来 even 把球扔过来 rather than 把球丟过来, and 扔垃圾 rather than 丟垃圾. The geneal meaning of 丢 is **lose**, 丢弃 or 抛弃 means **discard**, but single character 丢 does not.